# Add class to next and remove form closest

Tags: javascript

I have a function that worked in jQuery, but i need to rewrite the solution without using jQuery.

```
// Working in jQuery
var menu = jQuery('.menu');

menu.find('a').focus(function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('.visible').removeClass('visible');
  jQuery(this).next('ul').addClass('visible');
});
```

But I can not deal with a clean javascript

```
const menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');


menu.forEach(function(menu) {
    menu.addEventListener('focus', function() {

      // I tired replace this jquery into vanilla javascript
      jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('.visible').removeClass('visible');


      // Works
      const next = mainMenuLink.nextElementSibling;

      if (next) {
        next .classList.add('visible');
      }

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `.querySelectorAll(...)` in order to select the whole set of `ul` elements with class `visible`.

```
Array.from(this.closest('ul').querySelectorAll('.visible')).forEach((ul) => {
   ul.classList.remove('visible');
});
```